# What's the meaning of "Subscribed For Tracking" field in a triggered send?

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send, sales, email-tracking

I am copying a triggered send from env1 to env2 recreating it manually.
On env1 I saw that it contains this:

[image]

Please what is the meaning of it?

When this field is assigned to true?

Thank you